# Android Horizontal ProgressBar with a tooltip message to show the current state/progress

Tags: java, android, xml, frontend, progress-bar

I want to create a horizontal progress bar, but with a tooltip floating on the top of it to show messages/display current progress based on the progress bar.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Progress Bar]

The result should be something like this, *I'm sorry for the bad illustration, I was using Ms.Paint.

Additional: The message should be able to be changed dynamically from Java code.

Comment: there are alredy existing lot's of lib for this kind of feature

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya I can't find suitable libs, do you have some recommendations for this?

Comment: check out some of this use full lib:

https://androidhiro.com/source/android/example/indicatorseekbar/5937
https://github.com/zhou-you/EasySignSeekBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out some of this use full lib:

- https://androidhiro.com/source/android/example/indicatorseekbar/5937
- https://github.com/zhou-you/EasySignSeekBar